# Glassfish Admin Console - 404 error

Tags: console, glassfish, http-status-code-404, admin

I have several WARs in my Glassfish installation. Someday I found that Glassfish Admin Console disappeared. When I try to access [click here](https://myservername.com:4848/) - I see 404 HTTP Error.

Why Glassfish Admin Console is missing and how to return it back ?

I can't simple reinstall, because it is production server.

Answer (score 4):

Try access the console in this url: `http://myservername.com:4848/login.jsf`
In `http://myservername.com:4848` redirect to `http://myservername.com:4848/common/index.jsf` and not work because the url not exists.

I found this solution in this topic: https://www.java.net/node/699754

Answer (score 1):

It is old, but maybe can help someone. I had a similar issue now, and the reason of the problem was not enough space in disk. I removed some log files and after restart GF the admin console came back to work.